# Program not running when zipcode starts with 0 or ends with 0

Tags: java, barcode, zipcode

My assignment is to create a barcode for the user's input of a zipcode.  I can't find a way though, to make it give me a correct result if the user inputs a zip code that starts with a 0 (i.e. 05123) or has a check digit of 0 (i.e. 10027). Anyone have suggestions? I'm in a beginner java class.

```
public class Zipcode{

private String zipcode = "";
private String barcode = "";
private String tempCode = "";
private int zipnum = 0;
private int zipnumForCD = 0;
private int checkDigit = 0;
private int reversedZip = 0;
private int digitSum = 0;


 public Zipcode(int zip_number){
    zipnum = zip_number;
    zipnumForCD = zip_number;
    getCheckDigit();
    createUpdatedZip();
    createBarcode();
}

public Integer getCheckDigit(){
    while (zipnumForCD > 0){
        digitSum = digitSum + zipnumForCD % 10;
        zipnumForCD = zipnumForCD/10;
    }
    if (digitSum % 10 == 0)
    {
        checkDigit = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        checkDigit = 10 - digitSum % 10;
    }
    return checkDigit;  
}

public void createUpdatedZip(){
    zipnum = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(zipnum) + String.valueOf(checkDigit));
    for (int i = zipnum; i !=0; i /= 10){
        reversedZip = reversedZip * 10 + i % 10;
    }
}

public void createBarcode(){
   while (reversedZip > 0){
        switch (reversedZip % 10)
        {
            case 0: 
                tempCode = "||:::";
                break;
            case 1: 
                tempCode = ":::||";
                break;
            case 2: 
                tempCode = "::|:|";
                break;
            case 3: 
                tempCode = "::||:";
                break;
            case 4: 
                tempCode = ":|::|";
                break;
            case 5: 
                tempCode = ":|:|:";
                break;
            case 6: 
                tempCode = ":||::";
                break;
            case 7: 
                tempCode = "|:::|";
                break;
            case 8: 
                tempCode = "|::|:";
                break;
            case 9: 
                tempCode = "|:|::";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        reversedZip = reversedZip / 10;
        barcode += tempCode;

        }
    barcode = "|" + barcode + "|";
}

public String getBarcode(){
   return barcode;
}

}
```

and here is my tester class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ZipTest{

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a ZIP code: ");
    int zip = input.nextInt();
    Zipcode code = new Zipcode(zip);

    System.out.println("The bar code: ");
    System.out.println(code.getBarcode());
}
}
```

Comment: well, an `int` doesn´t have leading zeros, so you might want to reconsider that the zipcode is representable by an `int`. I´d switch over to a `String`.

Comment: @KevinEsche oh that's true! but how would you go about all these methods if it isn't an integer? i.e. having to divide the zip code by 10, etc.

Comment: @jaynepants You don't divide by 10, you extract the digit characters one at a time using `charAt()`.

Comment: Why did you just delete your question after someone put in effort to answer it, to help you?

Comment: And why are you degrading this question's text??

Comment: Question rolled back -- let your instructor see that you're dumping your homework on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of HashMap where you would store the barcode equivalent of each character from '0' to '9' int number.

```
Hashmat<Character, String> charBarMap = new HashMap<Character, String>();
intBarMap.put('0',"||:::"); 
intBarMap.put('1',":::||");
...
...
```

As you cannot have leading 0 in int, you would need to have your zip code in String format.

*From that string, retrieve each character and use the hashMap table to get the bar code string representation for that character('0' to '9') and keep appending to your string.*

```
 String st = "020080";

 StringBuilder barCode = new StringBuilder();

 for(int i=0; i<st.length(); i++){
      char c = st.charAt(i);
      barCode.append(charBarMap.get(c));
 }
```

Comment: I'd simply put the char value in for key.

Answer (score 0):

If the variabel is a string you can remove leading zero...then convert it to int.
Remove leading zero with String.replaceFirst(String regex).
To convert to int use something like this 
int foo = Integer.parseInt("1234")

Comment: You are aware that the goal is to **not** lose leading zeros?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is of a logical sort: the number 1234 ... what is that: 01234, or 12340?!

So, you **can not** represent a ZIP code as number. Instead, the only valid format for a ZIP code would be a **string** of length 5, that only contains digits!

In other words: your class should only take a string as argument to the constructor; and right there you do further validation (like checking for length/content) and throw an exception if the incoming zipcode isn't valid.

Thus: no conversion to an int in any place; everything happens with strings/characters. Of course, you can have methods that give you the number at index 0, 1, 2 ... as int; but in general, you better represent ZIPs as strings!